# Java project becoming too large

Tags: java, maven, ide, build-process

We have a large Java 8 Spring Hibernate Maven project that is getting larger.

**Problems :**

- Build time is 10-12 minutes at best; 3 minutes without tests
- We already have a command-line switch to skip rarely modified modules, which is the symptom of the build process reaching practical limits
- Eclipse is struggling to manage the project (although IntelliJ is ok for now)
- Things are getting worse as the project grows, and as more scenarios from the test team get incorported as integration tests in the code base.

**How we work now**

- The project is configured in about 20 Maven modules, like so:

```
    Parent
    |--- Tier1
    |--- Tier2
    |--- WebTier
         |---- ModuleA
         |---- ModuleB
         |---- ModuleC
         |---- ...
         |---- Entities
         |---- Shared
         |---- Batch
         |---- IntegrationTests
```

- The application is built as a single WAR
- Developers deploy a single tier (typically `WebTier`) as an artefact from Eclipse or IntelliJ to their local Tomcat
- Although the project seems nicely split in modules, there are many undesired coupling points between them. Specially in `Shared`, where modules needing "cross-modules" access put their services
- All integration tests are in a dedicated module (no idea why)

**Ideas to make it better**

- Add a `MessageBroker` module to allow loose coupling where relevant. Maybe JMS, or simply a dumb in-memory component for synchronous communication
- Get rid of the `Shared` module
- Make sure modules have coarse-grained entry-points
- Remove undesired coupling between siblings and prefer the message broker when possible
- Might keep `Entities`. At least the core-business entities (Customer, CustomerFile, ...). But some  entities obviously belong to a single module (a batch execution info would be in the `Batch` module)

That way, anyone making a change to `ModuleA` would most of the time only build and run tests in that module without fearing to break the application.

**Questions**

- Does that seem like a good plan? By good, I mean future-proof, with good chances to improve things, and not requiring an excessive amount of work given the situation
- Should we have 1 Eclipse/IJ project per tier, let the IDE build the artefact and deploy it to Tomcat, or should we have 1 project per module, and dependencies toward Nexus? Or maybe the latter option is overkill?
- Any other suggestions?

**Some metrics**

- Windows 7, Java 8, Maven 3.0.3, TestNG.
- SSD or 7200rpm HDD (limited impact)
- 6Gb RAM
- Heap 1Gb (maven)
- CI with Jenkins

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It sounds like you may need either a bigger heap or more RAM (or both).

Comment: Can you give a little more information about the size of the project? Really only 20 maven modules and take 10-13 minutes build time (sounds extremly slow). How many tests are running? How long do the tests take? Which Maven version are you using? How many line of code (measure by SonarQube?) Are you running a CI solution like jenkins? About what kind of command line switch are you talking about? Do you have a dedicated build machine? How many RAM/CPU etc. and what kind of hard disk does this machine has? How much RAM/CPU do the working stationgs have? Which operation system?

Comment: @khmarbaise The command-line switch is juste a `-DskipSomeModules` matching a maven profile to skip some of the rarely used modules. Nothing special here, just a quirk that shows we're not doing it right IMO. We have CI with Jenkins but it seems irrelevant here : it's the local dev build that hurts, and it can only be done by building the full WAR because of frequent coupling. Will get back to you with the requested info tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: That's the wrong way. Better use `mvn -pl TheModuleYouWouldLikeToBuild -amd` might be a better idea. Furthermore have you checked to run `mvn -T 3 ...` Apart from that use at maven 3.0.5 or higher (maven 3.0.3 contains serveral bugs)...

Answer (score 1):

CI would be real answer but it looks that your project is not modular as it should be. You don't build entire project from scratch every time. You build jars, test them in different projects and then use as single items. Each project should be small enough and cover just one area. Do you think that Java builds let's say security jars when they work on io package? Divide and conquer - that's the whole idea of OOP and encapsulation.

Comment: Not as modular as it seems for sure, hence my question on how I could make it better. I have to convince my teammates that the current situation is painful and will hurt the team in the long run, and that we can rely on a plan and trust the refactoring effort will be worth it.

Comment: This is more architectural question which cannot be answered without full analyzes. At least draw class diagram and see what connections are.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be as bad as you think.  Involved projects with unit tests and static analysis take a while.

A company I worked for had >1hr build + unitTest + CodeCoverage integration times.  That doesn't count the time needed to ship the artifact off to vSphere for automated clickthrough testing of the installer on 26 languages x 8 supported OSes.

Comment: I don't mind the 10' for a complete build per se. The trouble is that we have to do it each time we make a single change. If I modify things in ModuleX only, hopefully, I should not have to worry about ModuleA or ModuleB. We are never confident we're not going to break anything unrelated. It's the opposite actually. At the end of the day, these 10 minutes add up. However, common modules always call for a full build obviously.

Comment: Consider setting up parameterized build jobs in Jenkins so that you can tell the build script to build "module A" on demand, and then have hourly cron builds for full system builds.

This would solve the problem of a dev wanting ModuleA to get built and tested immediately, as well as the need to support full integration builds for regression and complete unit tests.

You could also have a separate ant /msbuild target (or whatever you are using) in the same Jenkins job that would build and unit test just that module on demand which passes the Jenkins Job parameter to the build script.